# How to use Python-Operator % for multiple values?

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x, format

I'm trying to fill an SQL database with soma data, measured by an bme680. Therefore I'd like to format the measured values like this:

```
print ("Temperatur: %0.1f C" % (bme680.temperature + temperature_offset))
print ("Gas: %d ohm" % bme680.gas)
print ("Luftfeuchtigkeit: %0.1f %%" % bme680.relative_humidity)
print ("Luftdruck: %0.3f hPa" % bme680.pressure)
```

To fill my table I use this command:

```
curs.execute("INSERT INTO bme680_tb (datum, uhrzeit, temperatur, gas, luftfeuchtigkeit, luftdruck) VALUES (CURRENT_DATE(), NOW(), %0.1f, 999.99, 999.99, 999.99);"%bme680.temperature)
```

But instead of 999.99 I would like to use more data from bme680 formatted with the %-operator.

How can I do that?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a quite simple solution: Split up the string like this:

```
string = "INSERT INTO bme680_tb (datum, uhrzeit, temperatur, gas, luftfeuchtigkeit, luftdruck) "
string += "VALUES (CURRENT_DATE(), NOW(), %0.1f, " %bme680.temperature
string += "%d, " %bme680.gas
string += "%0.1f, " %bme680.relative_humidity
string += "%0.3f" %bme680.pressure
string += ");"
```